# what relation use for retweet functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I'm following this tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

My question is, what is the relation for user can use retweet function?

e.j.

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :microposts
  .
  .
  .
end
```

If a user want make a retweet, **this relation is valid?** or would must I use **has_and_belongs_to_many?.** if the same tweet **belongs_to many user?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Twitter, the model seems to be that one tweet is *created by* one user, but *belongs to* (is shown on the timelines of) many users. That is, there are **two** relations between a tweet and user. The users in the *belongs to* relation that aren't the *created by* user are the ones retweeting the tweet.

Comment: Can you put a example model relations? Thank you

Comment: @hyperrjas Sorry, I don't have a Rails scratchpad project handy to test code, this is just an answer about the model design. Maybe wait a while to see if someone else makes a more thorough answer.